# multiple pictures give different shades for same scene and lighting

Tags: flash, macro, color

I am photographing an object 4 cm away from the camera using  5MP phone camera. It is being used in macro mode with fixed ISO 100 setting. Automatic White balance is being used along with center-weighted metering. The object and camera are enclosed in a box,so lighting does not change. Even when using fixed flash, different pictures can be seen to be visually different shades. The phone is the Samsung Galaxy Gt-S5380i. Is this normal? How can I prevent this. I need them to be same even after multiple pictures.
Thank you,
samc

Comment: Are you using fluorescent lights?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could post some examples. It may be that your phone is trying to be too clever and doesn't give you the control to tell it to stop.

Comment: I am using flash and I think it is LED flash so not florescent light.@mattdm

Comment: There is no Samsung Galaxy S5, do you mean S4?

Comment: Is it entirely dark except for the flash?

Comment: NO the walls are white and allow some light through just like when we put a torch light behind our fingernails. @mattdm

Comment: and the phone model is samsung gt s5380i. @thomasrutter

Comment: You have enough rep now to add sample pictures to your post. This will really help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming different shades means the color of each photo varies, I would blame the auto white balance algorithm of the camera.  The white balance decision is most likely being made at every shot, and then the answer seems to vary.

If you can set the white balance to a setting on the camera that is static but is a reasonable match for your scene (like outdoors or natural, not sure of the exact options for that phone), you should get consistent results.